# Metal vector literal initialization

Tags: metal

I would like to know if, in the Metal Shading Language

```
float3 x = 1;
```

is the same as:

```
float3 x = float3(1);
```

I indeed cannot find anything about it in the MSL specs.

Answer (score 1):

They are actually the same.

From the Metal Shading Language specs:

> Implicit conversions from scalar-to-vector types are supported. The
> scalar value is replicated in each element of the vector. The scalar
> may also be subject to the usual arithmetic conversion to the element
> type used by the vector.